# How can I manage many instances of a class in C++, giving them all information and then deleting them?

Tags: c++, instance, sfml, multiple-instances

I apologize for the imprecision on my language, I'm fairly new to programming.

Let's say I'm trying to create a particle effect in SFML. The solution I have at the moment is to create multiple instances of my particle class and then update them using a method in the class each frame that takes the updated position of the virtual "camera" as input, which works fine for one at a time. I'm having trouble making several at once, though, since in my current implementation I have to manually create and later overwrite each particle once a counter reaches a high enough value. How can I create, update, draw, and overall, just keep track of many instances at once? Is this possible to do, or should I rethink my implementation?

What I currently have, represented in English pseudocode:

```
Create a particle object()
while true{

    Update the particle instance's position(given camera position)
    Draw the particle instance

}
```

What I want to do (in pseudocode), but I'm not sure how to achieve in C++:

```
while true{

    Create a new particle object() // note: the particle objects already delete themselves after they have been updated a certain number of times, so creating new objects does not pose a threat to memory
    Update ALL particle instances' positions(given the camera's updated position)
    Draw ALL particle instances 

}
```

Roughly what I have in C++:

```
RenderWindow window(windowSize);
SmokeParticle smokeParticleInstance(cameraX, cameraY);
while true{

    window.draw(smokeParticleInstance.update(cameraX, cameraY)); // the update method returns a sprite object that the RenderWindow object knows how to draw

}
```

Comment: As the most simplest thing you can do, use a `std::vector<SmokeParticle>`. You can add new particles, you can loop over this collection, and you can remove elements. This will serve you fine well into the thousands or millions of particles.

Answer (score 0):

To create, update, draw, and keep track of multiple particle instances at once, you can use a container like a vector or a list to hold all the particle objects. Then, in your main loop, you can iterate over the container, update each particle's position, and draw it on the screen.

```
// create an empty vector to hold particle objects
std::vector<SmokeParticle> particles;

// add some initial particles to the vector
//This will add 10 particles to the vector
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    particles.push_back(SmokeParticle());


while (window.isOpen()) {

    sf::Event event;
    ...

    ...

    //update all particles
    for (auto& particle : particles) {
        window.update(time.asSeconds());
    }


    window.clear();
    //draw all particles
    for (auto& particle : particles) {
        window.draw(particle.sprite);
    }

    // display the window
    window.display();
}
```